# PrestaShop metrics definition

Tags: prestashop, documentation, metrics, looker-studio, kpi

I'm looking for a list of all the metrics from PrestaShop.
I looked on their website, forum, the Internet, and reached out to their support but, apparently, it doesn't exist?
I'm working on a Looker Studio report for a client and pull data from PrestaShop. There are many similar metrics and their difference is not obvious.
Would you know where I could find such a list?
Thanks!

Comment: Close vote: StackOverflow is for programming questions. PrestaShop usage or features is off topic here then.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification! It's really complicated to know where to ask. The support redirected me to GitHub, which is obviously for devs, and GitHub listed StackOverflow for 'other' questions. I guess now Slack is my only clue.